# Visual Studio is not re-generating Resources class anymore

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, resources, resx, .net-8.0

I have a C# Windows Forms application on .NET 8. All was fine, but the `Resources` class is not re-generated anymore when I add, edit or delete strings or images using the designer. I am not aware when exactly this stopped working.

There is no appropriate error output or so, when VS should re-generate the class. I already tried to clean and re-build the solution/project, but it has no effect.

Is there a setting or a log to check/change, or is it possible to manually trigger re-generating the `Resources` class?

Currently running VS 2022 v17.9.2

Comment: What is Resources class?

Comment: Ressources class is part of the Properties and auto-generated by VS based on the Resources.resx file, which you can edit in VS using a designer for strings, icons, images, audio, files, and other resources.

Comment: Did you set  resx`no code generation`? [png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTM8g.png)

Comment: I have no such option, only Custom, Internal, Public (selected is Custom)

Answer (score 1):

Custom option uses user-defined Custom Tool.
Please select Internal or public.